# x axis values not showing in scatter plot using ggplot package

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot, p-value

I have a dataframe that has rho value and p value for certain IDs.

my dataset:

```
dput(Corr_n)
structure(list(rsid = c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id6", 
"id7", "id8", "id9", "id10", "id11", "id12", "id13", "id14", 
"id15", "id16", "id17", "id18", "id19", "id20", "id21", "id22", 
"id23", "id24", "id25", "id26", "id27", "id28", "id29", "id30", 
"id31", "id32", "id33", "id34", "id35", "id36", "id37", "id38", 
"id39", "id40", "id41", "id42", "id43", "id44", "id45", "id46", 
"id47", "id48", "id49", "id50", "id51", "id52", "id53", "id54", 
"id55", "id56", "id57", "id58", "id59", "id60", "id61", "id62", 
"id63", "id64", "id65", "id66", "id67", "id68", "id69", "id70", 
"id71", "id72", "id73", "id74", "id75", "id76", "id77", "id78", 
"id79", "id80", "id81", "id82", "id83", "id84", "id85", "id86", 
"id87", "id88", "id89", "id90", "id91", "id92", "id93", "id94", 
"id95", "id96", "id97", "id98", "id99", "id100", "id101", "id102", 
"id103", "id104", "id105", "id106", "id107", "id108", "id109", 
"id110", "id111", "id112", "id113", "id114", "id115", "id116", 
"id117", "id118", "id119", "id120", "id121", "id122", "id123", 
"id124", "id125", "id126", "id127", "id128"), corr = c(0.934952164395629, 
0.910686864006669, 0.930059837275761, 0.816357691950044, 0.925239323487087, 
0.902390170332171, 0.920274138573169, 0.933926202783821, 0.958146168030846, 
0.920411262934275, 0.940965493186371, 0.936465241365378, 0.929970639947719, 
0.915074193184678, 0.889682912949839, 0.903330061150958, 0.915074193184678, 
0.950029788548565, 0.903330061150958, 0.889682912949839, 0.947041788196603, 
0.803605447587475, 0.925372169155952, 0.925372169155952, 0.903224237476806, 
0.933955452306938, 0.889679770631607, 0.919146607695895, 0.751128993600546, 
0.925443794164598, 0.960654731074051, 0.920402016684206, 0.872946286792529, 
0.958062320463817, 0.881615223565172, 0.958392723482937, 0.946178608843881, 
0.90829959102847, 0.918353267303984, 0.889719623336355, 0.94096603670015, 
0.94415952810264, 0.863687541951992, 0.86361781146622, 0.825274220340374, 
0.925632506392227, 0.847183026892012, 0.841902040940976, 0.937586281899818, 
0.95032358370767, 0.94414855813867, 0.943726378821856, 0.88664391079122, 
0.925631919997881, 0.933339452162141, 0.92061798516925, 0.919612957679819, 
0.889683382781085, 0.915072013305436, 0.92535088718382, 0.915272559644029, 
0.924344375745745, 0.9026742494792, 0.91516821455945, 0.880272424389888, 
0.903320237915045, 0.940202233220494, 0.889960718166183, 0.902379746941739, 
0.944156080551917, 0.817247401679312, 0.902345791625422, 0.937166086757865, 
0.903805121831112, 0.872448016217675, 0.930062720533937, 0.863685733586995, 
0.920331460075778, 0.937524686922676, 0.952542705718563, 0.925459444013743, 
0.960159307016849, 0.914832191162581, 0.925619824872472, 0.881615223565172, 
0.881489214906696, 0.903449803426646, 0.90982759271859, 0.914623237650392, 
0.941039402881587, 0.926531262290158, 0.89674608506498, 0.937605628280183, 
0.878594995946988, 0.900211472309499, 0.925092725453955, 0.920183247655887, 
0.853406859394636, 0.950030176517754, 0.955682378038783, 0.908963517075961, 
0.946867378958245, 0.925252759381424, 0.895400782042357, 0.91913393364972, 
0.933737765863219, 0.96655907381546, 0.9202563923255, 0.906450119910952, 
0.929947255973866, 0.953315019068652, 0.940220853517366, 0.937990519483778, 
0.960645095516695, 0.924184690064221, 0.94103047667854, 0.93378586951496, 
0.881373483562095, 0.9410460143559, 0.937766630063745, 0.929745892609813, 
0.941731572943261, 0.873270082896668, 0.933805379875372, 0.892350403085409, 
0.927932651948703, 0.947045963795882, 0.92996029027398), pvalue = c("0.0002118690694374", 
"0.00026308488486724", "0.00070484993149725", "0.00088342793282982", 
"0.00089969281273726", "0.00095625626066833", "0.00307816889794103", 
"0.00334568549642378", "0.00339864494961824", "0.00481535382790678", 
"0.00481535382790678", "0.00660445466557924", "0.00764434227225787", 
"0.00764434227225787", "0.00764434227225787", "0.00764434227225787", 
"0.00764434227225787", "0.00764434227225787", "0.00764434227225787", 
"0.00764434227225787", "0.00764434227225787", "0.00764434227225787", 
"0.00764434227225787", "0.00764434227225787", "0.0078277208585352", 
"0.0115397045957251", "0.0115397045957251", "0.0140779029458078", 
"0.0150579714577512", "0.0197881057481875", "0.0197898099613507", 
"0.0215191532899952", "0.0215191532899952", "0.0246216153164539", 
"0.0274086629991561", "0.032954479808064", "0.0344081978664664", 
"0.0345100898198675", "0.0435914001980873", "0.0435980949615047", 
"0.0435980949615047", "0.0451687447107746", "0.0451687447107746", 
"0.0508011296179234", "0.0648895903300949", "0.0697326429444134", 
"0.0709536216660615", "0.0715147992163933", "0.0788408082086297", 
"0.0809293638661076", "0.0823680777596502", "0.0896054864434418", 
"0.0956525104821812", "0.0957562786854422", "0.0957562786854422", 
"0.0957562786854422", "0.0976196418847593", "0.104465873612382", 
"0.106833472632844", "0.106833472632844", "0.107475347310097", 
"0.11068697727484", "0.126150764855425", "0.14377893219712", 
"0.154323417882195", "0.156009865827704", "0.17440795565029", 
"0.177229984361821", "0.183032024396735", "0.188048768850889", 
"0.191699208310582", "0.196919576816204", "0.220127260333427", 
"0.227553616807578", "0.230805625978978", "0.238698857794745", 
"0.238698857794745", "0.238698857794745", "0.238698857794745", 
"0.2559848955185", "0.259198799140294", "0.269176925197184", 
"0.289895623821287", "0.289895623821287", "0.312040934992537", 
"0.318141606666907", "0.318911210914388", "0.319442636540046", 
"0.321119909131389", "0.32952913111269", "0.344393628448912", 
"0.355093197783839", "0.355093197783839", "0.382084461781353", 
"0.383607993152143", "0.388300338453881", "0.399547088387142", 
"0.470400199588203", "0.490693614490964", "0.492304167343793", 
"0.499040970288875", "0.542502183036992", "0.549166912433013", 
"0.566179572879549", "0.567426075472232", "0.674477409919487", 
"0.68588704183079", "0.68588704183079", "0.69423733480229", "0.702561306710734", 
"0.723454085678846", "0.773842773679014", "0.78229924581066", 
"0.810397696543416", "0.859507690578278", "0.893368122468456", 
"0.933231564503113", "0.950614873380497", "0.973950437945092", 
"0.977843368740407", "1.10524547799898e-06", "1.71318094466417e-11", 
"1.71497115213503e-06", "1.93744902020634e-06", "1.95606081221237e-09", 
"3.37730930462203e-06", "8.93935575744768e-07", "8.93935575744768e-07"
)), row.names = c(NA, -128L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I am plotting scatter plot but in my case the x axis range or values doesn't show up or is showing as a smear.
I want to add the values. Is there any way to show the values on x axis properly and not like the one I am getting.

My code

```
g <- ggplot(Corr_pvalue,aes(y=corr,x=as.numeric(pvalue)))+geom_point()
```

Or I need to scale x axis in order to do it?

[image]

how to do this?

The plot with as.numeric p value
[image]

Comment: Your pvalues are characters and not numeric.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem Rhea. Removing `as.numeric` from the `ggplot` call in your code gives me the smear, but with as.numeric, I get a normal-looking x-axis

Comment: Hello Mark,  I have edited my post to add the entire dataset to reproduce the code as well the plot with as.numeric as you mentioned but it only gives certain p value being plotted and remove the extreme small p value with 1.93744902020634e-06", "1.95606081221237e-09", 
"3.37730930462203e-06", "8.93935575744768e-07", "8.93935575744768e-07"

Comment: @RheaBedi, it is possible that your points are there in the plot, but they are on top of each other. Consider that your extreme points on your x axis scale are essentially 0, and the correlations of these are around 0.92-0.94. What happens if you use `+ scale_x_continuous(trans='log10')`?